# Environmen PATH with Pycharm remote connection

Tags: python, ssh, environment-variables, pycharm, remote-server

I have a remote server and I want to use Pycharm to execute my scripts on this remote server using SFTP and SSH. Everything works properly, except that, when running the scripts on the server through the Pycharm "Run" command, the PATH is wrong. I am trying to understand which file I should edit to properly set the PATH environmental variable. I am using a mac and the server runs ubuntu. After having installed several libraries on the server, I edited the .bashrc file in my home directory on the server to properly set up the PATH. Then the following happens:

- If I login to the server using ssh and the mac terminal, the PATH is loaded correctly.
- If I open a ssh session inside pycharm and connect to the server, the PATH is loaded correctly.
- If I run a simple script (that only contains calls to the standard library) on the remote server through the Pycharm "Run" command, it works
- If I run the full script on the remote server through the pycharm "Run" command, then in crashes: os.environ['PATH'] shows that the path is not correct
- If I run the script by directly calling the python interpreter on the server using one of the terminal ssh session, then the PATH is set up properly and it works

So apparently the PATH is set up properly if I connect to it using ssh and the terminal, but when Pycharm tries to run it directly the PATH is not updated and it crashes.

So I am guessing pycharm doesn't look into .bashrc before running the program. Which file should I modify then? Note that the only "configuration" files present in my home directory on the remote server are .bashrc and .profile.

*Note* I do not have sudo privileges on this server.